# Why DecimalForm make TableView malfunction?

Tags: tableview

I have some imported data that include big numbers, and I don'y want them to be displayed in `*10^8` format.

The following code demonstrate the problem:

```
TableView[{{1, DecimalForm[2.3*10^8]}, {2, DecimalForm[2.55*10^8]}}, 
 ImageSize -> 1200, Editable -> False]
```

The output is just repeating my input, only DecimalForm[2.3*10^8] and DecimalForm[2.55*10^8] is calculated.

Comment: With wrappers the numbers are no longer numbers. For this example you could just use `Round`: `TableView[{{1, 2.3*10^8}, {2, 2.55*10^8}} // Round, ImageSize -> 1200]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The literal answer to your question is that controls need to specify what kind of inputs they take.  If you look at [ref/TableView](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableView.html), you'll see that the default inputs are strings and numbers.  `DecimalForm[number]` is a general expression (just like `f[1]`), not a number.  So you need to add second argument of `Expression`.

However, there appears to be a bug specific to `DecimalForm` and related wrappers like `NumberForm` that causes `DecimalForm` not to display correctly inside `TableView`.  You see the "raw boxes" instead of the number.  I'll file that as a bug, but I guess there's a reason why this is feature is still marked experimental...

**Update**: the bug mentioned in the last paragraph is known, and there's every reason to believe it will be fixed in time for 12.1.1 (out later this spring).

Comment: Finally I used `Dataset`

Comment: If you're using it just for display purposes, `Dataset` is probably better in any event.  `TableView` is really a control, like a slider or checkbox, rather than formatting wrapper.